# How can I open pdf files in kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I ran into a problem in a project where I needed to open a PDF file in a **Kivy app**, and I've been struggling to fix it. If you could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

I had written some code that might be useful, but it couldn't send the address to the PDF viewer and had trouble with the PDF viewer. However, it worked perfectly until it asked which PDF viewer to choose for opening the file :

```
class FileScreen(Screen):

    def open_pdf(self):

        # Define the path to the PDF file

        pdf_file_path = "assets/files/cat/PLT_Sondex/All.pdf"

        

        if platform == 'android':

            # Create an Intent to open the PDF file with AndroidPdfViewer

            from jnius import autoclass

            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')

            Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')

            

            intent = Intent()

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

            uri = Uri.parse(f'{pdf_file_path}')

            intent.setDataAndType(uri, 'application/pdf')

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

            

            try:

                current_activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

                current_activity.startActivity(intent)

            except Exception as e:

                print("Error opening PDF:", e)

        

        else:

            print("This feature is only supported on Android.")

            if os.path.exists(pdf_file_path):

                os.system(f'start {pdf_file_path}')  

                print("start")
```

I want to open pdf in my kivy apk for Android 12 or higher, with Android default pdfviewer.